# when php's mysql_query returns 0, it produces an error. how to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

when the user doesnt have any tags to display, query returns `: Undefined variable: tags in` last line of the function.

what is the best way to handle this error?

i was thinking of doing if `$tags == 0 {$tags=''}; else return $tags;` but this didnt work.

```
function show_users_tags($userid){

    $sql="SELECT id, tag_name from tags WHERE user_id='$userid'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        $tags[] = array(    'tag_name' => $data->tag_name, 
                            'id' => $data->id       
                    );
    }
    return $tags;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When no results are found in your query, the `while` loop won't be executed and the `$tags` variable will never be written to, causing the notice `Undefined variable` when returning it.

Put `$tags = array();` on top of your function to initialize the variable to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
$tags = array();
```

outside of while loop.